# Random bystanders helping Reacher out

Tags: plot-explanation, jack-reacher

During the <strike>Camaro</strike> Chevelle chase scene, Reacher simply walks out of his moving car and joins a crowd waiting for a bus (or possibly a tram) while the police converge on the still moving vehicle. Why does everyone of the bunch of random people also waiting for the bus help him out by not alerting the police nearby? Two of them (one African American, the other Caucasian) shield him from view, while one (African American) hands him his baseball cap.

Once he escapes, Reacher returns the cap to its owner who smiles to himself.

What is the rationale behind this supposed to be? Does a similar scene also occur in the book, *One Shot*?

Comment: @Tom I didn't read much into the entire movie :) I'm just curious what the director, scriptwriter, or author were trying to convey.

Comment: @coleopterist I was just about to post the same question :) Sadly I can't find a satisfying answer even here :(

Comment: Not trying to be nit-picky ... the chase scene you are talking about ... the car is a 70 SS Chevelle. I love cars more than I love movies ... and I *really* love movies.

Comment: One of the most clever chase scenes I have ever seen. Being from a big city like Pittsburgh, most people have had a run in with a police officer now and again. (Think Stop and Frisk in New York) The police do not have the credibility they once had, and big cities know the corruption that has overrun the police. If you've ever spent anytime actually living in Chicago, New York, LA...it is quite obvious the mentality of not helping the police, and don't trick on people. Imagine if every citizen did that for each other, how great the US would be. Absolutely genius and hilarious scene.

Answer (score 15):

I'd say that whoever added this scene, may it be the screenwriter, producer, director, <strike>author of the book</strike> or someone else, was just looking for a more or less original and clever way of ending the car chase and letting Jack Reacher get away. And, by having him jump out of the car when no one sees and then just letting it continue down the road while he's heading in some other direction by foot (in this case to a crowded bus stop) they managed to do just that.

*I have actually read the book now and there are no car chases at all in it, so the chase and the scene(s) right after were definitely added afterwards.

Fun Fact: The notable bathroom fighting scene was also just a movie addition.*

When it comes to the reactions of the people already at the bus stop, I don't think there's anything out of the ordinary. Sure, they could've had some people run off, but, when you see some guy getting chased by a dozen police cars and he walks over and stands right next to you, I think most people would just stand there quietly and hope that the police sees him. Not many people would try to get the attention of the police since that would most likely also get the attention of the perpetrator, possibly leading to them getting hurt or maybe even killed.

The two men who hid Jack from the police are just there as comedic relief. But, I wouldn't say that it's totally unrealistic. Without having any kind of statistics backing me up on this, I'd say that people who have been arrested before, and especially people that have been unjustifiably arrested (which, sadly, happens sometimes, and especially to non-Caucasian citizens like the two gentlemen in the movie) would help others hide from the police, as long as it's not too much trouble.

Comment: I would also add that I think most people don't trust in the police.

Comment: @jsedano I would also add that I think most people do trust the police, at least in the United States...

Answer (score 2):

I like to think that they decided to not turn him in because Americans often are rooting for the person being chased in high speed pursuits. Anecdotally, Americans seem more exposed to high speed chases on the news and on live television, and honestly, it doesn't seem unlikely that a group of people would not report someone who simply walked away from a high speed chase, because it rarely happens that the pursued suspect escapes and it is often assumed that the police are overreacting.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange! Your answer raises some very interesting points, but would be much better if you could provide some evidence or source material to add greater credibility to your claims.

Answer (score -1):

Its one of the weaknesses of having Tom Cruise play Reacher.  Imagine yourself in the same situation except a 6.5' monster is standing next to you.  Yea you'll give him your hat.

Add to this the stereotyped inner city attitude towards cops and it is very realistic.

Answer (score -3):

The guy in the hat was a former baseball player:  The significance is that Reacher sometimes uses these guys as aliases in his books.

Comment: Um... pretty sure this isn't true. Do you have any sources to back up this claim?

Comment: @Catija, Jimmy Reese and other Yankee's second basemen. However, #Eric Pittman the actor in the scene, Tommy Lafitte, is not a former baseball player and rather someone who has had small parts in a couple of films.